# Custom Repository with access to findAll specification method

Tags: java, spring

In need to do a custom dynamic search in the repository layer. Can't do the query via query method or via query annotation.
This dynamic search need to call findAll(Specification, Paging) who are implemented by  pleJpaRepository spring class

```
public interface CardsRepositoryCustom {
    public Page<Cards> customSearch(CardSearch CardSearch, Pageable page);
}

public interface CardsRepository extends JpaRepository<Cards, Integer>, CardsRepositoryCustom {

}

@Repository
public class CardsRepositoryImpl extends SimpleJpaRepository implements CardsRepositoryCustom{

    public CardsRepositoryImpl(Class<Cards> domainClass, EntityManager em) {
        super(domainClass, em);
    }

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

     @Override
     public Page<Cards> customSearch(CardSearch CardSearch, Pageable page) {
        Specification<Cards> specification = (Root<Cards> root, CriteriaQuery<?> cq, CriteriaBuilder cb) -> {
            ..
        }
        return this.findAll(specification, page);
     }
}


@Service
public class CardsServiceImpl implements CardsService {

    @Autowired
    public CardsServiceImpl(CardsRepository CardsRepository) {
        this.CardsRepository = CardsRepository;
    }

    public CardsRepository CardsRepository;

    @Override
    public Page<Cards> customSearch(CardSearch CardSearch, Pageable page) {
        ...
        return CardsRepository.customSearch(CardSearch, page);
    }
    ...

}
```

When i run application i get

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.dwengo.cards.repository.CardsRepositoryImpl required

Comment: first parameter of CardsRepositoryImpl constructor is useless because Class<Cards> can only be obtain with Cards.class. So use directly Cards.class when calling super.

Comment: Change nothing Parameter 0 of constructor in com.dwengo.cards.repository.CardsRepositoryImpl required a bean of type 'java.lang.Class' that could not be found.

Comment: so you didn't remove it from the definition... and you need to set autowired on the constructor.

Comment: when we extends SimpleJpaRepository class, we have choose of two constructor: (JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) or (Class<T> domainClass, EntityManager em) with @Autowired    
    public CardsRepositoryImpl(Class domainClass, EntityManager em) {
        super(Cards.class, em);
    } that don't work

Comment: Don't specify the class and just do super(MyDomain.class, em);

Comment: @JEY, exactly what i done, tried both way Cards.class and domainClass, result it's the same.

Answer (score 3):

Spring detect a that bean CardsRepositoryImpl need to be construct however no @Autowired or @Inject are defined in the constructor. So spring try to create an instance using default (no args) constructor. It fail because two parameters are needed and the first one (index 0) is of type Class.

Once you add @Autowired to the constructor spring try to resolve dependencies and can't find a bean of type Class. Completely understandable. Moreover the Class parameter is here useless.

Change your definition with:

```
public class CardsRepositoryImpl extends SimpleJpaRepository<Cards, Long> implements CardsRepository {
    private final EntityManager em;
    @Autowired
    public CardsRepositoryImpl(EntityManager em) {
        super(Cards.class, em);
    }

    @Override
    public Page<Cards> customSearch(CardSearch CardSearch, Pageable page) {
        Specification<Cards> specification = (Root<Cards> root, CriteriaQuery<?> cq, CriteriaBuilder cb) -> {
        ..
        }
        return this.findAll(specification, page);
    }
}
```

Comment: that work, already tried to put autowired on the constructor, but did not thinking about removing first parameters... like you said it was useless.